# Run a countdown timer depending on YouTube video current time

Tags: javascript, timer, youtube

I made an ad video like YouTube does, so it becomes skippable after 10 seconds or so.

The problem is the countdown timer starts to count immediately even if the video didn't start yet, and I want to make a javascript condition so the timer starts only if the video's current play time is greater than 0 (Once the video starts to play).

```
// Countdown timer  
var counter = 10;
var interval = setInterval(function() {
  counter--;
  if (counter == 0) {
      $('#skip-counter').hide(); // Hide counter
      $('#skip').fadeIn(); // Show skip ad button
      clearInterval(interval); // End interval
  }
  else {
    $('#timer').text(counter); // Printing time
  }
}, 1000);
```

Check the codepen here

https://codepen.io/petersherif/pen/xOZzjQ?editors=0010

I've searched google and stackoverflow a lot and found some solutions, but unfortunately I can't get what I want from them.

Hope anyone help me, and thanks in advance :) .

Answer (score 1):

Great, very cool stuff, I've solved my problem and here is the answer to my question.

I've used the YouTube API with the help from this js fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/oo1g1762/1/

```
var myTimer;   

// This code loads the IFrame Player API code asynchronously.
var tag = document.createElement("script");
tag.src = "//www.youtube.com/iframe_api";
var firstScriptTag = document.getElementsByTagName("script")[0];
firstScriptTag.parentNode.insertBefore(tag, firstScriptTag);

// This function creates an <iframe> (and YouTube player)
// after the API code downloads.
var player;
window.onYouTubeIframeAPIReady = function() {
  player = new YT.Player("player", {
    "height": "315",
    "width": "560",
    "videoId": "bHQqvYy5KYo",
    "events": {
      "onReady": onPlayerReady,
      "onStateChange": onPlayerStateChange
    }
  });
}

    // 4. The API will call this function when the video player is ready.
    function onPlayerReady(event) {
      event.target.playVideo();

    }
  function onPlayerStateChange(event){
      if(event.data==1) { // playing
          myTimer = setInterval(function(){ 
              var time;
              time = player.getCurrentTime();
              $("#timeHolder").text(time);
          }, 100);
      }
      else { // not playing
          clearInterval(myTimer);
      }
  }
```

Which is an answer to this question [YouTube API - Getting current time in a global variable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30746064/youtube-api-getting-current-time-in-a-global-variable)

And here is my own code

```
var myTimer;   

// This code loads the IFrame Player API code asynchronously.
var tag = document.createElement("script");
tag.src = "//www.youtube.com/iframe_api";
var firstScriptTag = document.getElementsByTagName("script")[0];
firstScriptTag.parentNode.insertBefore(tag, firstScriptTag);

// This function creates an <iframe> (and YouTube player)
// after the API code downloads.
var player;
window.onYouTubeIframeAPIReady = function() {
    player = new YT.Player("player", {
        "videoId": "D3C3mAub0vA", //Here is the video ad ID
        "events": {
            "onReady": onPlayerReady,
            "onStateChange": onPlayerStateChange
        }
    });
}

// The API will call this function when the video player is ready.
function onPlayerReady(event) {
    event.target.playVideo();
}

// Countdown timer
var time;
function onPlayerStateChange(event){
    if(event.data==1) { // playing
        var counter = 10;
        myTimer = setInterval(function(){ 
            time = Math.floor(player.getCurrentTime());
            if (time >= 0) {
                counter--;
                if (counter == 0) {
                    $('#skip-counter').hide(); // Hide counter
                    $('#skip').fadeIn(); // Show skip ad button
                    clearInterval(myTimer); // End interval function
                }
                else {
                    $('#timer').text(counter); // Printing time
                }
            }
        }, 1000);
    }
    else { // not playing
            clearInterval(myTimer);
    }
}
```